# Difference between [recording] [record] and [copy] [file-copying]

Tags: discussion

Since these don't have tag wiki's, what is the difference between [recording](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/recording) and [record](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/record)?
It looks like they overlap.

It also looks like both [copy](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/copy) (from tag wiki: "copying in the context of file managemenent") and [file-copying](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/file-copying) refer to the action of copying files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[record](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/record) and [recording](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/recording) are both horrible tags that provide nothing useful.

[record](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/record) should be removed from all questions. [recording](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/recording) should be replaced by more meaningful tags like [audio-recording](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/audio-recording) or [video-capture](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/video-capture) (which should possibly be renamed [video-recording](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/video-recording)).

Afterwards, [record](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/record) is hopefully automatically removed by the system.

---

[copy](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/copy) *should* refer to the Windows command-line utility `copy` (like [cp](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cp)). If that was the case for some questions, the tag wiki excerpt should reflect that and questions should be retagged appropriately. As it currently stands, the tag is not useful at all. [file-copying](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/file-copying) is somewhat more useful, as it is more specific.

To resolve this, I would adjust the tag wiki for [copy](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/copy) to reflect that it is intended for questions involving the Windows command-line utility. Then I would take all questions that are about file copying and are tagged with [copy](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/copy) and retag them with [file-copying](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/file-copying). If the Windows utility `copy` is involved in the problem, leave the [copy](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/copy).